# Getting a Sitecore Commerce Sellable Item List Price at Indexing Time

Tags: sitecore-commerce, indexing

I am indexing Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2 sellable items through a regular `SitecoreItemCrawler`. The HabitatHome demo sellable items are in my content tree at `/sitecore/content/Habitat Sites/Habitat Home/home/Catalogs/Habitat_Master`. Items synchronized there from Sitecore Commerce do not have a any price field, not even a list price. Thus, I am trying to build a computed index field to get the list price from Sitecore Commerce.

I know Sitecore Commerce APIs have a `GetBulkPrices()` method that returns the information I want. I can call it using Postman with the "CatalogAPISamples/Catalog - Pricing/Get bulk prices" request:

- URL: https://localhost:5000/api/GetBulkPrices()
- Method: PUT
- HTTP Headers

  - ShopName: CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront
  - ShopperId: ShopperId
  - Language: en-US
  - Currency: USD
  - Environment: HabitatAuthoring
  - GeoLocation: IpAddress=1.0.0.0
  - Authorization: Bearer + Access_Token
- Body: `{ "itemIds": ["habitat_master|productSku|"] }`

However, I cannot find the way to call this method from Sitecore code without crafting my own HTTP request. I have looked in `Sitecore.Commerce.Connect` and other places without success. I have tried the following approaches:

1. PricingServiceProvider + GetProductPricesRequest

   ```
   PricingServiceProvider pricingServiceProvider = new PricingServiceProvider();
   GetProductPricesRequest getProductPricesRequest = new GetProductPricesRequest(productSku);
   getProductPricesRequest.SetShopName("CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront");
   GetProductPricesResult productPricesResult = pricingServiceProvider.GetProductPrices(getProductPricesRequest);
   return productPricesResult.Prices.ContainsKey("List") ? productPricesResult.Prices["List"].Amount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null;
   ```

   It ends with this exception that does not provide much insight:

   ```
   ManagedPoolThread #4 16:16:43 ERROR An exception occurred while trying to process the item {E1E4CDD3-01C1-0854-7EBC-6F64C1A01F1F}: Default Control Panel Storefront
   Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
   Message: Default Control Panel Storefront
   Source: Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common
      at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStorefront.get_ControlPanel()
      at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStorefront.get_CurrencyConfiguration()
      at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStorefront.get_CurrencySet()
      at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStorefront.get_DefaultCurrency()
      at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Providers.CurrencyProvider.GetSelectedCurrency()
      at Sitecore.Commerce.Services.ServiceProvider.RunPipeline[TRequest,TResult](String pipelineName, TRequest request)
      at Sitecore.HabitatHome.Foundation.CoveoIndexing.ComputedFields.ListPriceComputedField.GetPriceFromApi(IItem p_Item, String productSku)
      at Sitecore.HabitatHome.Foundation.CoveoIndexing.ComputedFields.ListPriceComputedField.GetListPrice(IItem p_Item)
      at Sitecore.HabitatHome.Foundation.CoveoIndexing.ComputedFields.ListPriceComputedField.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable p_Indexable)
      at Coveo.SearchProvider.Documents.AbstractDocumentBuilder.AddComputedFields()
      at Coveo.SearchProvider.Documents.DocumentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateIndexableItem>b__3()
      at Coveo.SearchProvider.Documents.AbstractDocumentFactory.TryBuildDocument(Action p_Action, IIndexable p_Indexable)
   ```
2. PricingServiceProvider + GetProductBulkPricesRequest

   ```
   PricingServiceProvider pricingServiceProvider = new PricingServiceProvider();
   GetProductBulkPricesRequest getProductBulkPricesRequest = new GetProductBulkPricesRequest(new List<string> { productSku });
   getProductBulkPricesRequest.SetShopName("CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront");
   GetProductBulkPricesResult productBulkPricesResult = pricingServiceProvider.GetProductBulkPrices(getProductBulkPricesRequest);
   Price listPrice = productBulkPricesResult.Prices["List"];
   if (listPrice != null) {
       return listPrice.Amount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
   ```

   It ends with a very similar exception than the first approach.
3. PricingManager.GetProductPrices()

   ```
   IConnectServiceProvider connectServiceProvider = new ConnectServiceProvider();
   IItemTypeProvider itemTypeProvider = new ItemTypeProvider();
   ISiteContext siteContext = new SiteContext(itemTypeProvider) {
       CurrentCatalogItem = p_Item.SitecoreItem
   };
   PricingServiceProvider pricingServiceProvider = new PricingServiceProvider();
   IPricingManager pricingManager = new PricingManager(connectServiceProvider) {
       PricingServiceProvider = pricingServiceProvider
   };
   IModelProvider modelProvider = new ModelProvider();
   IStorefrontUrlManager storefrontUrlManager = new StorefrontUrlManager(siteContext);
   IContext defaultContext = new DefaultContext {
       Item = p_Item.SitecoreItem,
       Database = p_Item.SitecoreItem.Database
   };
   IStorefrontContext storefrontContext = new StorefrontContext(modelProvider, storefrontUrlManager, defaultContext);
   ICurrencyProvider currencyProvider = new CurrencyProvider(storefrontContext, defaultContext);
   CommerceStorefront commerceStorefront = new CommerceStorefront(currencyProvider, defaultContext);
   ICartManager cartManager = new CartManager(connectServiceProvider);
   IAccountManager accountManager = new AccountManager(connectServiceProvider, cartManager, storefrontContext, modelProvider);
   IVisitorContext visitorContext = new VisitorContext(accountManager);
   ManagerResponse<GetProductPricesResult, IDictionary<string, Price>> managerResponse = pricingManager.GetProductPrices(commerceStorefront, visitorContext, HABITAT_CATALOG_NAME, productSku, false, "List");
   return managerResponse.Result.ContainsKey("List") ? managerResponse.Result["List"].Amount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null;
   ```

   It ends with this exception because there is no `HttpContext`:

   ```
   Exception: System.NullReferenceException
   Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   Source: Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common
     at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Context.SiteContext.set_CurrentCatalogItem(Item value)
     at Sitecore.HabitatHome.Foundation.CoveoIndexing.ComputedFields.ListPriceComputedField.GetPriceFromApi(IItem p_Item, String productSku)
     at Sitecore.HabitatHome.Foundation.CoveoIndexing.ComputedFields.ListPriceComputedField.GetListPrice(IItem p_Item)
     at Sitecore.HabitatHome.Foundation.CoveoIndexing.ComputedFields.ListPriceComputedField.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable p_Indexable)
     at Coveo.SearchProvider.Documents.AbstractDocumentBuilder.AddComputedFields()
     at Coveo.SearchProvider.Documents.DocumentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateIndexableItem>b__3()
     at Coveo.SearchProvider.Documents.AbstractDocumentFactory.TryBuildDocument(Action p_Action, IIndexable p_Indexable)
   ```

All of my approaches seems to require an `HttpContext` that is a request to the storefront site matching a Sitecore site element.

Is there a way to call the Sitecore Commerce Engine to get the price of a product without a Sitecore site context?

Comment: Ah, the good old ServiceLocator pattern lives on

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1.

Just wrap your code in `SiteContextSwitcher`:

```
using (new SiteContextSwitcher(Factory.GetSite("YOUR_COMMERCE_SITE_NAME")))
{
    // get price here
}
```

## Option 2.

Review `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.SellableItemsCrawler`, not `SitecoreItemCrawler`. It does request to CE to get list of Sellable Items with all required price information, you need.

For example, you could extend `GetItem` method in `SellableItemsCrawler` to add custom field to index:

```
protected override CommerceCatalogItemIndexableItem GetItem(SellableItem catalogEntity, string artifactStoreId)
{
    var indexableItem = base.GetItem(catalogEntity, );
    // here we get sellable item price:
    var pricesPolicy = sellableItem.Policies.OfType<ListPricingPolicy>();
    var prices = pricesPolicy.SelectMany(pricePolicy => pricePolicy.Prices).Select(money => money.Amount)
                .ToList();
    // here we add custom field to index:
    indexableItem.InternalFields.Add(new CommerceDataField("listprice", prices.FirstOrDefault());
    return indexableItem;
}
```

*Note*. Of course, don't forget to add new field to index configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Why not go all the way, lets borrow the code from the previous answer and than put in in the Commerce Engine.

1. Create a custom index handler
2. Update the json config - PlugIn.Search.Solr.PolicySet-1.0.0.json
3. Do a bootstrap, and don't forget to stop start your Minions service. So the the index minions are updated.

Custom Index handler:

```
public class PriceHandler : AbstractIndexFieldHandler
    {


        public ComposerValueSource ComposerSource { get; set; } = new ComposerValueSource(string.Empty, string.Empty);


        public override object ComposeValue(object source, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> context)
        {
            if (context == null || !(source is CatalogItemBase catalogItemBase))
                return null;


            if (!(catalogItemBase is SellableItem))
                return null;


            SellableItem sellabelItem = catalogItemBase as SellableItem;

            if (ComposerSource.PropertyName.Equals("ListPrice"))
            {
                var pricesPolicy = sellabelItem.GetPolicies<ListPricingPolicy>();
                var prices = pricesPolicy.SelectMany(pricePolicy => pricePolicy.Prices).Select(money => money.Amount)
                            .ToList();

                return prices.FirstOrDefault();
            }


            return null;

        }
    }
```

PlugIn.Search.Solr.PolicySet-1.0.0.json:

```
{
            "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrIndexFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr",
            "Name": "ListPrice",
            "Type": "System.Decimal",
            "Handler": {
              "$type": "MyCompany.Commerce.Plugin.Pricing.IndexFields.PriceHandler, MyCompany.Commerce.Plugin.Pricing",
              "ComposerSource": {
                "PropertyName": "ListPrice"
              }
            }
          }
```